# What is wrong in this construction?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

> After a 1991 attempt to overthrow Mikhail Gorbechav failed, power *had shifted* to Russian president Boris Yeltsin.

Why is "had shifted" wrong here?

Comment: I would use the past simple here --> "Power shifted ....". Past simple is an action that has been completed, (which is more appropriate in this context). e.g. "He talked".

Comment: @parkgatedev Yeah that would be correct but I can't understand the grammar why this form is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your sentence as a single sentence you have two actions in the past

1 the attempt failed

2 then power shifted.

Action 2 in your sentence is in past perfect. This automatically implies that action 2 was in a time before action 1, and that is wrong.

Example

He returned home again because he had forgotten to take his purse with him.

Comment: I like such comments. Thanks. They are seldom, though.

Comment: That's not true at all, though. In the question's quote, there's no implication that the shift in power came before the attempt to overthrow Gorbachev; the implication is that both of them came before, and affected, some third event, that Random Codemonkey is about to talk about.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect tense is used when the exact moment of the event is either unknown or unimportant.  As far as your question goes, I think what is meant that measured at some point in the fall of 1991, President Yeltsin's power was apparently higher than that of Gorbachev's thus suggesting that the shift of the said power took place prior to that point, but when exactly is not possible to pinpoint or is just irrelevant.

If that statement was made then (at some point after 1991 attempt to overthrow MG), the speaker could say, "The power **has shifted** to Yeltsin", and since to us now 1991 is in the past (and even to the author of that statement it likely was at the time of writing), we (or the author) use **past perfect** tense ("had shifted").

Answer (score 0):

> After a 1991 attempt to overthrow Mikhail Gorbechav failed, power *had shifted* to Russian president Boris Yeltsin

is grammatical and could be the right tense to use, depending on the context. In general, we use the perfective tenses (present perfect and past perfect) to describe activity that sets the stage or establishes the context for what we're really thinking or talking about.

You should use *power had shifted* if the paragraph you're writing is about events that happened as a result of the shifting power, but *power shifted* if the paragraph is about the shift of power itself.

On another topic, you might write,

> In the fall of 1944, the Western Allies seemed poised to invade Germany and end the war. Since the Normandy landings in June, British and American forces **had advanced** all the way to the Rhine. Now they searched for an opportunity to cross the river. British commander Montgomery thought he **had found** that opportunity, at a weakly-defended bridge in Arnhem, Netherlands. To exploit it, he planned a massive operation called Market Garden.

The advance of Allied armies up to the Rhine is *background* to the topic. Montgomery's (imagined) identification of a weak point is the context in which the plan was laid.